# ARToolkit Error in MVC2010 : Error LNK1236 libARvideod.lib

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build-error, artoolkit

when I build the example project of ARToolkit in Visual Studio 2010, I got this following error :

**Error 46  error LNK1236: corrupt or invalid COFF sections C:\Program Files\ARToolKit\examples\paddleDemo\libARvideod.lib(libARvideod.dll) paddleDemo**

I followed this tutorial :
[Tutorial ARToolKit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dbEPLRPdxxw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your error as I do not have VS 2010. Also I cannot understand what the person in the video says as I don't understand the language.

However, you can have a look here for more information about how to build ARToolKit5:
http://artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=8_Advanced_Topics:build_artoolkit

Also on this page you find some more information about the simpleLite example.

Also as your question is related to build libARVideo this documentation might help:
http://artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=8_Advanced_Topics:windows_building_libarvideo

On the ARToolKit forum there is a Community-page a the top which leads to a forum which you can use to ask for help about ARToolKit.

Tell me if you got further